# Why i'm getting a javascript null reference when reloading iframe in internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an `iframe` and I am using jQuery to change the `src` and reload it. It is working fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in Internet Explorer it gives me a null reference error. Here is my code:

```
function reloadIframe(url) {
    $('#frameId').attr('src', url);
    document.getElementById('#frameId').contentDocument.location.reload(true);
}
```

It is changed after a click event:

```
$(document).on("click", ".link", function () {
    reloadIframe('@Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller")');         
});
```

The iframe:

```
<iframe id="frameBuyRecharge" width="100%" frameborder="0" src="some link"></iframe>
```

Please help me!

Comment: Try using `contentWindow` instead of `contentDocument`.

Comment: I have tried this too, but it is the same.

Comment: `document.getElementById('#frameId')`? Does your frame have `id="frameId"` or `id="#frameId"`?

Comment: it is    id="frameId"